# Is it safe to remove the /home/Systemback folder?

Tags: backup, systemback

I am unsure where this folder comes from. Thus prior to deleting it, I am seeking your advice as to whether it can be safely deleted.

**What creates this folder? Is this a default folder?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: At some point in the past, did you try Systemback as your backup method? If so, did you later discard Systemback in favor of another backup method?

Comment: Yes, maybe but I actually really don't remember anymore! Anyway, I have all my files backed up differently and will delete this folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Systemback software](https://launchpad.net/systemback) creates this folder.

It is not a default [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=systemback&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) as it comes from the PPA in the first link, so it's not a default folder.

You can safely delete pretty much anything that you have backed up via a method that you have proven that you can safely recover.

Answer (score 1):

The OS doesn't use files from the `/home` folder or it's hierarchy for operation.  Any files in that area will be something that you or one of your users would have created, that shouldn't affect normal systemwide operation.

If you or users of your system have creates files in that space, you would have to check and decide if you still have a need for those files.

In the case of the particular name, it's a backup utility that may have been installed for backing up your system.  You can run the program to ensure your backed media is in a safe place (not actually in that folder), then safely delete the folder.

Most applications that are manually compiled have an install feature to install the application systemwide.  Applications from the repository or that use *deb installations does this automatically.  After you have installed a program systemwide, you can delete the work/source directory and access the application from the Dash Search or your regular search path.